# Remove ice from freezer surface

Tags: home, kitchen, water, temperature, appliances

I just discovered that my ice cube tray has been leaking. There is significant layer (1/2" thick) of ice underneath it. It's about the same dimensions as the tray (5" x 12").

**Is there an easy / quick way to remove the ice?**

Some notes:

- I imagine that the ice will slowly vanish over time because it's a "frost free" freezer, but I'm looking for a quicker solution that that.
- I am loath to chip at it with anything too sharp. I punctured a freezer doing that one time in college.
- I had thought of aiming a hair dryer at it, but it seems as though that wouldn't be very effective.
- I would rather not unplug my refrigerator to let the whole thing thaw.

**EDIT**

To clarify, I did not know that some units allow the freezer to be turned off independently of the refrigerator. As Stan suggested in his answer, this may be an option.

Comment: Is the freezer separate from the refrigerator (separate door) or located inside at the top of the refrigerator (one door)?

Comment: My freezer has a separate door from the refrigerator. It is an independent compartment. I did like your answer; however, I found a different solution which worked for me because of the material on the "floor" of the freezer. I'm adding that answer below, now.

Answer (score 5):

**I found the answer to my own question.** However, it will only work on some brands and models of refrigerator-freezers.

LateralTerminal suggested using a brush on a drill. Instead I used what was on hand: a kitchen scrubber brush. To my surprise, when I scraped it across the ice, with some pressure, the ice sheet cracked! That led me to discover that the bottom of the freezer is a flexible plastic, rather than the rigid metal I assumed it was. I was able to tap on the ice sheet and break it up into pieces. Once the ice sheet was broken, I could remove each of the pieces. The freezer is now ice-free.

Answer (score 2):

You could carefully use one of these.

Make sure you don't scratch the surface of your fridge

[image]

Too show I'm not biased and don't work for this company here's a few more variations.

[image]

I'm not sure what else to add here. I know you we don't like answers that are just pictures.

It's a drill with a brush attachment. Probably a bad idea to use a metal attachment but hard stiff plastic could take it off pretty quick.

Comment: Very interesting! I didn't know that these existed. With some hot water this would probably work very well. Thumbs up!

Comment: Drill brushes can answer a lot of questions here actually. There's endless uses

Comment: Do you think they can join the ranks of duct tape, WD-40, and lint rollers? (I'm a huge fan of lint rollers.)

Answer (score 1):

This just happened to me last week when I tried to remove an ice tray stuck to the bottom. It created a tiny hole where the ice stuck the tray when I pulled it free.

While I don't have a frost-free freezer (3F alliteration) You could try a partial defrost of yours manually. It's not rocket science - you'll think of things to help it along. No tools necessary. (Cheat: I did use a wooden spoon to push the bottom of the tray free.)

Open the door of the freezer and turn off the freezer. I have an "off-cool-cold-coldest" temperature selection dial which I turn to "off."

As the freezer warms to room temperature, some water will tend to accumulate on the bottom of the freezer. I absorb it with a small kitchen towel.

You could put a hot dish-cloth (hot water, soak and wring it so that it isn't dripping wet.) or a fan to blow room temperature air into the freezer to speed the thawing. I know some might use a hair dryer to spot-thaw the tray. I don't have one.

At some point, you'll be able to lift the block of ice off the freezer bottom.
With my freezer (which was set to -18°C) it took about 20 minutes to half an hour.

Restart the freezer as soon as you free the tray and ice .

The refrigerator will remain cold enough to prevent your food from spoiling during this minor frustration.

EDIT: This technique worked for a combined (one door) refrigerator-freezer. A separate freezer may need a different procedure than this given one.

Comment: To speed this up I place pans of hot water on all the shelves. NB I like to defrost the freezer in winter because I can take out the drawers/baskets and put them outside so the stuff doesn't thaw. If I have to do it in summer I stack the drawers and put a blanket over the top. My freezer came with a plastic spatula just for this, but a plastic pancake flipper is also helpful.